# d.ts declaration for R.js framework

Tags: typescript, typescript1.5

I need help to create the declaration file of https://github.com/keithamus/R.js

I don't know how to solve R('item') problem. I need the .d.ts file to be an external commonjs module to be able to use like this:

```
import R = require("/i18n/R");
R('item'); // my problem
R.setLocale("en");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare module "R" {
  interface R {
    (name: string): void;
    setLocale(locale: string): void;
  }
  var RModule: R;
  export = RModule;
}
```

Comment: just removed declare module "R" and it worked as expected. Thank you.